# Selecting only associations between engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I need to grab all users that have an application. `User` is part of my core engine, which is used by many other engines. I'd like to keep User unaware of what is using it, which is why I don't want to add `has_many :training_applications` in my `User` model.

Here are the classes

```
module Account
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  end
end


module Training
  class TrainingApplication < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user, class: Account::User

  end
end
```

The following obviously won't work because `User` has no concept of `TrainingApplication`:

```
Account::User.joins(:training_application).distinct
```

Is there an elegant way to return a distinct collection of `User` objects that are associated with a `TrainingApplication`?

What I landed on as a quick solution is

```
Account::User.where(id: Training::TrainingApplication.all.pluck(:user_id))
```

but I'm thinking that there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is no way you can add a `has_many :training_applications` association to the User, the following should be suitable solutions:

You could type up a joins string yourself:

```
t1 = Account::User.table_name
t2 = Training::TrainingApplication.table_name

Account::User.
joins("INNER JOINS #{t2} ON #{t2}.user_id = #{t1}.id").
group("#{t1}.id")
```

For the sake of variety, let me cover the subquery method as well:

```
Account::User.where("id IN (SELECT user_id FROM #{t2})")
```

I would go with the `joins` method but I believe both solutions will be faster than your current implementation.

Comment: Not as clean looking, but certainly faster and only uses one query. Thanks.